# :last-child issue when adding a footer after a section

Tags: html, css

Right, so this is strange. This code works as expected:

HTML:

```
<section>
    Section #1
</section>

<section>
    Section #2
</section>

<section>
    Section #3
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section{
    margin-right: 30px;
}
section:last-child{
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

The first two sections get a right margin of 30px, while the third section doesn't get a right margin.

Now, if I add a footer element after the last section, the :last-child will be ignored. That way, all three sections will have a right margin of 30px. This holds true in both Mozilla and Webkit.

Has anyone got a clue why this is, and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:last-child` means *last child*, it has no bearing on the rest of the selector, it's an independent restriction.  This means it has to be the last child, **regardless of element type or class**, etc...it is literally the last child element.  Since your footer is after this, there's no matching element that's *both* a `<section>` *and* a `:last-child`.

The selector for this is [`:last-of-type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-of-type-pseudo), but it's not as widely supported.

Comment: Ah, that makes total sense! Thanks a lot.